# HttpWebResponse not getting full response if Content-Length is 67722

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest

In my code, I am doing below

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

`httpWebRequest` is a POST request whose response size in Fiddler after one redirection is 67722. `response.ContentLength` field returned in my case is -1 and total size of `responseFromServer` is approximately 32695. It simply cuts the remaining data from response. I have seen somewhere to use `maxReceivedMessageSize` but not able to figure our how to do it.

> responseFromServer.Length 32695
>
> response.ContentLength -1
>
> response.GetResponseHeader("transfer-encoding") ""

**UPDATE: FINAL**

Response was coming right. Issue was with my code where parameters being sent into POST query were not encoded properly through UrlEncoding. If we are dealing with [ASP.net contentpanel control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), point to remember is that it sends the POST query with control names having special character '$'. We need to encode that using [HttpUtility.UrlEncoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

Comment: Is the `transfer-encoding` header set to `chunked` in the response?

Comment: <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

add this is web.config

Comment: @spender it is set to empty string as determined by `response.GetResponseHeader("transfer-encoding")`

Comment: @UthistranS.This does not help as mine is a desktop windows forms with app.config only where I made this update. I need to set maxReceivedMessageSize somehow not maxRequestLength. Request is going fine.

Comment: Are the string contents what you expect albeit truncated?; You don't need to configure any limit for this to work. HttpWebResponse will not just silently truncate your data. There are no limits.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by spender, check the response headers..the value for 'ContentLength' is supplied in the response headers, and may NOT be the actual length of data; if transfer-encoding is 'chunked', it is "normal" to mark contentlength as -1.

I'm not familiar with fiddler..but perhaps it is fetching things that the webresponse is not, like external scripts? Try loading the page in a normal webbrowser, and 'View Source' --> use some tool (A textbox..) to count the characters in the source: is it actually 67k or closer to 32? Similarly, check the last part of data in 'responseFromServer'..is it the same as when 'Viewing page source'? ie. both are probably (hopefully?) < / h t m l >

Comment: transfer-encoding is not marked as chunked. Size is closer to 67K. Lot of Javascript is downloaded. Last part is not same as view page source.

Comment: Please show the line where you declare/create 'reader'. 
edit: You say size is closer to 67k; how did you measure? Also, what is the last data in 'responseFromServer' & what comes directly after this when viewing page source

Comment: I think there is something else wrong with my code. I disabled the redirection and then noticed that I am being redirected to home page rather than to the desired page. This may have something to do with cookies and session maintenance. I will update once beyond that.